# how to display string embedded with url in its back in ios 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am posting my APP name to my follower say EXAMPLEAPP i dont want to paste the url. I would like to implement it in html way say ***a href:"http://www.EXAMPLEAPP.com">EXAMPLEAPP /a>"*** this html code give me EXAMPLEAPP in blue color, on clicking it will redirect to the url to which it points at back end.
 see the image:

[image]

In the image blue color words say "Greek alphabet"," Cumaean alphabet", "ruled early Romen" etc ..are having web links. 
Exactly that kind of solution i m looking for is it possible? thanks in advance

Comment: there are many solutions, `UIWebView`, `DTCoreText`, your own parse and normal `CoreText`. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: i m using TWTweetComposeViewcontroller i have checked html tags to set as initial text but it is not working even after posting tweet with html content the follower is getting all the tags i typed in the tweet view controller

Answer (score 1):

you can display the embedded string but only using the UIWebView.

```
outputHTML=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<body> %@ </body>", stringData];

[webView loadHTMLString:string baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Well you could also use CoreText for the mark up and handel the links your self. [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) does this all for you without using `UIWebView`.

Comment: ya Sure, but thats not in apple documentation thats why avoided.

Comment: Well DTCoreText uses Apple's own CoreText, there is nothing there that isen't in the Apple documentation.

Comment: i m using TWTweetComposeViewcontroller i have checked html tags to set as initial text but it is not working

Comment: `TWTweetComposeViewcontroller` does not support any kind of formatted text. Thus HTML is not suported.